# Can ActiveRecord in Rails generate database schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Hi Does anyone know if a model in Rails can be used to generate a database schema?

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more. Do you want to generate a schema from an existing database ?

Comment: This question, as written, does not make any sense.  Please clarify what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for migrations in Rails: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

If you use the rails generators to create your models then your migrations are also generated for you and all you have to run is

```
rake db:migrate
```

in order to get your schema in the database

You can also refer to schema.rb to look at your current state of the schema